# Output to console in Mongo server-side javascript

Tags: mongodb

Anybody figured out a way to output to a console inside a javascript function executing server-side in Mongo?  Groovy code below:

```
DBCollection js = db.getCollection('system.js')
js.save([
    '_id' : 'product',
    value : new Code("""
        function(x,y) {
            alert('product called!');  // blows up...
            console.log('product called!');  // blows up...
            return x*y;
        }
    """
    )
])
js.eval('product(2,3)')
```

Comment: the js `print()` function can, though I cannot think of a reason to. Edit: In fact I have no idea why this piece of code even exists, you are evaling to a single threaded js engine built into MongoDB

Comment: @Sammaye - reason: just want to periodically indicate progress in a long running batch update script.  `print()` works great.  Add it as an  answer so I can accept it!

Comment: @Sammaye - good question on the edit.  I'm not sure either why it exists either.  I'm finding that when you have to update millions of documents at a time in batch that Mongo's working set keeps growing until it consumes all the memory on the machine and starts hard faulting like crazy...  I'm hoping that server-side execution may be treated a bit differently.

Comment: Nah this is a part of MongoDB due to the LRU of the OS your are running on. Since this is a mass update script do you really care about it page faulting? I mean you of course probably don't mind if it take a while? It is just eval is so hard on a server, plus it doesn't work with sharding and f course with this you take javascript lock.

Comment: I didn't intend to use eval in the end really.  The docs indicate that running .js files through the Mongo shell on the server does not lock and is best for batch administrative work. The code above was just a proof of concept for the javascript rather than the way it will be executed I guess.

Comment: Ah ok that's better yea you can run this through console perfectly fine. About the working set, it is very hard to solve this when updating millions of records sequentially, even if you was able to use the atomic locks etc since of course MongoDB has to page in the documents, it can't do it any other way. Hmmm, I wonder through, if you were to do the update call using multiple cursors in a loop so it destroys each cursor after like 1 million records I wonder if that could trick the LRU into ditching the old paged in data...

Comment: That being said though, it isn't a true problem so long as it doesn't crash your server which it shouldn't, the memory controller should detect when other apps want memory and should give it them, hopefully.

Comment: Interestingly enough, yesterday I tried the range technique to fetch say 1000 records at a time and update them.  Execution was still sequential, but no cursor had greater than 1000 documents.  I thought Mongo might ditch the old paged data, but alas, it did not...  It doesn't crash the server, but it slows progress down to such an extent that updating any more than a million or so records takes prohibitively long.

Comment: Hmmm I gotta admit I am now drawing a blank, I do remember something about mass updates but I have since forgot :) Some one else might know or it might be good posting a benchmark and that on `mongodb-user` google group, I am sure some one there might be able to get to the bottom of it. I mean the default answer to increase RAM but that isn't really a good answer since this is a one off job and isn't truly representative of your working set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two functions you can use to output from within JavaScript that is eval'd on the MongoDB server (including Map/Reduce functions):

- `print()` - standard javascript print
- `printjson()` - print as JSON

Both functions will emit their output into the `mongod` log, and can be useful for debugging.